# Proof involving linear combinations and gcd of two numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Here is the question that I'm working on:

> Suppose $d$ is a common divisor to $a$ and $b$. We want to show that $d | (ma+nb)  \forall m,n \in \mathbb{Z.}$

**What I know so far...**

The question does not specify what kind of numbers $a$ and $b$ are, so, for the sake of this problem, let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}.$ I know that when computing the gcd of two numbers, say $a$ and $b$, I have a list of calculations I need to do and the last *non-zero* remainder is what yields our gcd. Now, this question is asking us to do a linear combination of some sort and my initial response was to work backwards. What I mean is that for every equation that I got from performing the Euclidian Algorithm, I solve for the remainder and use that value to substitute it into the next equation that follows above and continue the pattern from there until I get a linear combination. I hope that I'm explaining myself well here. Any inputs and inquiries are greatly appreciated.

John.

Comment: The proof can be phrased as though $a$ and $b$ are integers (*certainly they wouldn't be arbitrary real numbers*), but it could be generalized to any euclidean domain.  Use the straightforward definition of divisor.  What does it *mean* by *definition* for $d$ to be a divisor of $a$?  It means that $a=kd$ for some integer $k$.  Rely on the same definition for $b$ and then notice what happens when you use these observations in $ma+nb$.

Comment: Use (or prove) that $d \mid u \implies d \mid ku$ and $d \mid u, d \mid v \implies d \mid u+v\,$.

Comment: Assuming those properties have explicitly been proven either in class already or as an earlier homework assignment @dxiv.  I would have done this from first principles personally.

Comment: Unfortunately, those properties (the second comment of this thread) that were mentioned haven't even mentioned in lecture, nor have I come across it in my reading.

Comment: Technically $a,b$ do not need to be integers. But you must have some well-defined meaning to "x is a divisor of y".  Usually that means there exists an integer, $k$ so that $kx =y$.  That will hold true if $m,n$ are integer and that there are integer $k,j$ so that $kd =a$ and $kd =b$.  But... yeah, you can assume they are integers.  It's just too obscure otherwise.

Comment: @JMoravitz Right, of course. Even if they weren't done in class (the `or prove` part of my comment), I still think it's useful to recognize (and remember for the next time around) that not only does $\,d\,$ divide the sum $\,ma+nb\,$, but it does in fact divide each of $\,ma\,$, $\,nb\,$ separately, and therefore their sum.

Comment: How do I prove that $d | u, d | v \Longrightarrow d | u+v?$ Once I know how the proof looks like, I should be able to complete the proof.

Comment: @JohnSmith read through my first comment very carefully.  Suppose that $d\mid u$, this means that $u=dk$ for some integer $k$.  Then also $d\mid v$ implies that $v=d\ell$ for some integer $\ell$.  We then have $u+v=dk+d\ell=d(k+\ell)$, which means...  This same proof can be very quickly and easily modified to fit the proof for $ma+nb$

Comment: "certainly they wouldn't be arbitrary real numbers"  Why not?  Well, okay, they can't be *arbitrary* because they must have a common divisor (and the word "divisor" must be defined in terms of integers), but say $d = \sqrt 2$ and $a = 7\sqrt 2$ and $b = 5 \sqrt 2$.  Well certainly $\sqrt 2$ is a divsor of all $m7\sqrt 2 + n5\sqrt 2$.

Comment: Definitely makes sense now. It's now just a matter of putting the puzzle pieces together.

Comment: "Now, this question is asking us to do a linear combination of some sort"  No.  It is not.  It is asking you to assume that someone else has done the calculations and that they figured out the answer was $d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$, then you can write $a=a'd$ and $b=b'd$. This means that: $$ma+nb=ma'd+nb'd=(ma'+nb')d$$

So $d\mid ma+nb$.